# how to compute how many bits of information about a given sentense?

Tags: information-theory

I am learning Stanford CS224N: natural language processing with Deep Learning.

the professor [said something](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT5DW2DKqHA&feature=youtu.be&t=1231) and claim that what he said was about 200 bits of information.

how to compute how many bits of information about a given sentense ?

Comment: If you google "entropy of English language" you might find some relevant information.